# Find all integers

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic

How can I solve this problem of Chinese Girls math 2019?

Find integers $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_{18}$, s.t. $a_1=1,a_2=2,a_{18}=2019$, and for all $3\le k\le 18$, there exists $1\le i<j<k$ with $a_k=a_i+a_j$.

[Original Problem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1894065p12935048)

Any brilliant ideas? I know the numbers are 1.2.3.5.8.13.21.34.55.89.144.233.267.500.508.
1008.1011.2019

Comment: Your problem is unclear. You seem to be saying three of the eighteen values are known and you have to determine the other fifteen, but what relationship is claimed between them, and what does "there is $1\le I$" mean?

Comment: Do you have a link to the original problem?  Your version seems to have left off necessary conditions.

Comment: here https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1894065p12935048

Comment: Well, you left off a *lot* of the problem statement.  "$1\leq I$" is nowhere close to the phrase "$1\leq i < j < k$ with $a_k=a_i+a_j$"

Comment: In any case, this does not seem to be uniquely determined at all.  There are surely dozens if not hundreds of valid solutions.

Comment: I have edited your post to include the original question.  If I have introduced an error, please correct it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Just for fun*; There will be $$\prod_{i=4}^{17} (f_{k+1}-2)$$
number of possible $18$-tuples of integer satisfying above condition.
where $f_{i}$ is $(i)th$ fibonacci number.

---

**If you want to calculate:**

*Given : $a_1=1$ and $a_2=2$
So by the construction $a_k=a_i+a_j$ for $1 \leq i < j < k$*

- The possibility for $a_3$ is 1 i.e., $a_3=a_1+a_2=2+1=3$
- Now we'll try to construct $a_4$ in all possible ways:

  *$a_4=a_1+a_2=3$ or  $a_4=a_1+a_3=4$  or  $a_4=a_2+a_3=5$*

  > S0 possibility for $a_4$ are $3,4,5$
- *Now let us try for $a_5$*

  $a_5$ by above construction $a_5$ can have all numbers that $a_4$
  have and in addition to it $a_5$ will also have $6,7,8$
- *Similarly, $a_6$ :*

  clearly $a_6$ will have all elements of $a_5$ and
  in addition to it, it will also have

  > $z_6=\{a_5 -a_3\}+(greatest/last \;element \;of \;a_4)$

  so possibility for $a_6$
  is $\{3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13\}$

**Let's do one more for better understanding i.e. $a_7$**

- $a_7$ will have all the elements of $a_6$ and in addition to it, it
  will also have

  > $z_7=\{a_6 - a_4\}+(greatest/last \;element \;of \;a_5)$

---

**Note at every step say $ith$ we are adding $f_{i-1}$ additional consecutive numbers to the set, where $f_{i-1}$ is $(i-1)th$ fibonacci number.**

i.e., if we are to calculate the possibility set for $a_k$ then it will have numbers

> $\{a_{k-1} \}$ $\cup$ {$f_{k-1}$ consecutive numbers after last
>   element of $a_{k-1}$}

*Let's see what we got:*

$|a_4|=3=f_2+f_3$

$|a_5|=|a_4|+f_4=f_2+f_3+f_4$

.

.

$|a_k|=\sum_{i=2}^{k-1}f_{i}$

And we know that,

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}f_{i}=f_{n+2}-1$$

So, $$\sum_{i=2}^{k-1}f_{i}=f_{k+1}-2$$ as $f_1=1$

Now if we seek to find to the total number of possible integers which satisfy the above condition.

$a_1,a_2,a_3,a_{18}$ **are fixed and have only one possibility** so we will focus on $4 \leq i \leq 17$

Now by simple combination rule, we will have

Total number of possible $18$-tuples $$= \prod_{i=1}^{18} |a_i|$$

Which is actually $$= \prod_{i=4}^{17} (f_{k+1}-2)$$

Comment: You really are amazing

Comment: @EsposaDoYoongi Thanks, I hope there is no flaw in it and you are able to understand every step.

Comment: Can I kill the problem by stating this?
a1 = 1
a2 = 2
a3 = 3 (easy to deduce)
a4 <= 5
a5 <= 8
...
a18 <= 2019


if the last equality is valid, all the others must be valid

Comment: @EsposaDoYoongi I don't think the bound on $a_{18}$ is correct

Comment: If my calculation is correct then $3 \leq a_{17}$ $\leq 2585$